# Compositor: Export movie files

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

I have a composition with multiple file out nodes, and I would like to output movies from some of them instead of an image sequence. Is this possible ?

If I use the video sequence editor, I can't find an easy way to different clips with unique names at once. If that's something do-able, then it would serve my needs as well

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

File output node only saves separate image files per frame. To make a a movie file you would need to add the frame seq to a VSE timeline and recompress. There is no built in way for Blender to achieve multiple movie exports from one scene. You could set up many VSE scenes with a image seq strip in each then perform a command line render of them.